# Adding id to an iframe using javascript in console

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to add an id to an iframe using javascript in the console. Is that possible?

```
<iframe src="www.example.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Select the frame and assign to its `id` property??

Comment: @CertainPerformance I need to do this in the console.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that won't make a difference, you can type Javascript in the console just like you can type Javascript in a `<script>` tag or in a userscript?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm trying to select a radio button inside an iframe, but I can only do it for iframes with ids. If they don't have ids, I can't do it, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to add ids to iframes. document.getElementById("top").contentWindow.document.querySelector("input[value='female']").click()

Comment: It doesn't work if the iframe have a class name, but no ids.

Comment: There's a couple of ways there;s always a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` method:

```
var myframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];

myframe.id = "newID";
```